# Are all points in a Banach separable space subsequential limits?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a Banach separable space. By separability, there exists a countable **set** $\mathbb{M}$ that is dense in $\mathbb{X}$. Then, every point of $\mathbb{X}$ is a limit of some sequence in $\mathbb{M}$. However, I wonder: can I order $\mathbb{M}$ in a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that every point of $\mathbb{X}$ is a subsequential limit of $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: The answer is yes, and any order of $M$ will work.

Comment: In every neighborhood of every point in $X$ there are an infinite number of points of $M$ from the sequence.